# Navigate between UserControls with Event Aggegator

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, eventaggregator

I have a MainWindow where I navigate between UserControls by clicking on a menu and it works fine.

I am using this following pattern:

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/

In one of those usercontrol there is a button. By clicking on this button I want to navigate to another usercontrol.

How do I do that?

## **MainView**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cvm:FirstViewModel}">
        <cv:FirstView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cvm:SecondViewModel}">
        <cv:SecondView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <cvm:MainViewModel x:Key="main"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource main}}">
    <Border Grid.Row="0">
        <Menu Height="58">
             <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}" Width="289" Height="58">
                 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock>
                             <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource main}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" TextDecorations="{x:Null}">
                                 <InlineUIContainer>
                                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                 </InlineUIContainer>
                             </Hyperlink>    
                         </TextBlock>
                      </DataTemplate>
                 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             </ItemsControl>
        </Menu>
    </Border>       
    <Border Grid.Row="1" >
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentUserControl}"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

## **MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            PageViewModels.Add(new FirstViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new SecondViewModel());

            // Set starting page
            CurrentUserControl = PageViewModels[0];
        }

        #region Fields

        private List<IUserContentViewModel> _pageViewModels;
        public List<IUserContentViewModel> PageViewModels
        {
            get
            {
                if (_pageViewModels == null)
                    _pageViewModels = new List<IUserContentViewModel>();

                return _pageViewModels;
            }
        }

        private IUserContentViewModel _currentUserControl;
        public IUserContentViewModel CurrentUserControl
        {
            get { return _currentUserControl; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _currentUserControl)
                {
                    _currentUserControl = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentUserControl");
                }
            }
        }

        #region Methods

        private void ChangeViewModel(IUserContentViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!PageViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
                PageViewModels.Add(viewModel);

            CurrentUserControl = PageViewModels
                .FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);


        }

        #endregion

        private ICommand _changePageCommand;
        #endregion
        public ICommand ChangePageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_changePageCommand == null)
                {
                    _changePageCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        p => ChangeViewModel((IUserContentViewModel)p),
                        p => p is IUserContentViewModel);
                }

                return _changePageCommand;
            }
        }
    }
```

## **SecondView**

```
<Grid Background="Blue">
    <Button /> <!-- Going to ThirdView?????????-->
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally have my solution.

I use Event Aggregator with Prism 6.

First I create a Singleton.

```
internal sealed class ApplicationService
    {
        private ApplicationService() { }

        private static readonly ApplicationService _instance = new ApplicationService();

        internal static ApplicationService Instance { get { return _instance; } }

        private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        internal IEventAggregator EventAggregator
        {
            get
            {
                if (_eventAggregator == null)
                    _eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();

                return _eventAggregator;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then `public class GoToThird : PubSubEvent<TEvent> { }`

In `MainViewModel` I subscribe to the event and add my `ThirdViewModel()`.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
        protected readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            PageViewModels.Add(new FirstViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new SecondViewModel(ApplicationService.Instance.EventAggregator)));

            PageViewModels.Add(new ThirdViewModel());

            // Set starting page
            CurrentUserControl = PageViewModels[0];

            this._eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        }

        private void GoToThird()
        {
            CurrentUserControl = PageViewModels[2];
        } 
}
```

At the end I publish the event in `SecondViewModel()`

```
public class SecondViewModel
    {

        protected readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

        public SecondViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            this._eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        }



        private void Go()
        {
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<GoToThird>().Publish();
        }


        private ICommand goToThirdCommand;

        public ICommand GoToThirdCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return goToThirdCommand ?? (goToThirdCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.Go(), p => this.CanGo()));
            }
        }

        private bool CanGo()
        {
            return true;
        }
}
```

Big Thanks to Rachel and Kirenenko

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `ChangePageCommand` from your button:

```
<Button DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource main}}"
        Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand"} 
        CommandParameter="{Binding PageViewModels[2]}">
```

I am assuming that you have your `FirstViewModel` stored at `PageViewModels[0]`, and your `SecondViewModel` at `PageViewModels[1]`.

You also have to create a `ThirdView` link to your `ThirdViewModel`, as your other two Views/ViewModels:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    ...
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cvm:ThirdViewModel}">
        <cv:ThirdView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And just as an advice, you can set your UserControl DataContext at the start of your code, instead of using it in any UIElement(Button and Grid in your case), like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <cvm:MainViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

**EDIT>>>>**

Forgot to say that you also have to add your ThirdViewModel to your PageViewModels collection:

```
PageViewModels.Add(new ThirdViewModel());
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but we are very close. If I write CommandParameter="{Binding PageViewModels[3]}" (which is empty), the button is isEnable = '"false", so the biding works

Comment: @Cantinou Its PageViewModels[2] -> your ThirdViewModel. Not [3]. Did you checked the edit?

Comment: So, look at the output console of visual studio and check if some binding is failing. I cannot help you If I dont know what is failing.

Comment: I don't see the the problem. The CurrentUserControl is well changed in CurrentUserControl = PageViewModels
                .FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);

Comment: @Cantinou Does the ContentControl not change at all? and there is no binding fail neither? Are your ThirdView UserControl `InitializeComponent()` called?

Comment: Nop InitializeComponent() is not called

Comment: Then the third view is not being created. Check the names of your "ThirdView" and your "ThirdViewModel", anyone of this could be wrong typed on `DataTemplate` part

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I was on vacation. I have checked the names, they are right.

Comment: I asked the same question but adding my real code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780547/navigation-with-usercontrols