# Navigation with UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a CateringMenuView where I navigate between UserControls by clicking on a menu and it works fine.

I am using this following pattern:

https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/

In one of those usercontrol (NewRegularOrderView) there is a button. By clicking on this button I want to navigate to another usercontrol. In order to do that I used the answer I have here:

[Navigate between UserControls with Event Aggegator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431473/navigate-between-usercontrols/34431656#34431656)

But when I click on the button nothing happens.

Could you help to find why?

## **CateringMenuView**

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cvm:NewDeliveryComOrderViewModel}">
            <cv:NewDeliveryComOrderView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cvm:NewRegularOrderViewModel}">
            <cv:NewRegularOrderView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cvm:FillOrderViewModel}">
           <cv:FillOrderView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <cvm:CateringMenuViewModel x:Key="menu"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource menu}}">
        <StackPanel>
           <Menu>
              <MenuItem Header="New Order">
                 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <TextBlock>
                              <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource menu}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" TextDecorations="{x:Null}">
                                 <InlineUIContainer>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                 </InlineUIContainer>
                              </Hyperlink>
                            </TextBlock>
                          </DataTemplate>
                       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                   </ItemsControl>
                 </MenuItem>
              </Menu>
         </StackPanel>


        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8" >
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentUserControl}" Margin="0,0,-1,0"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

## **CateringMenuViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            PageViewModels.Add(new NewRegularOrderViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new NewDeliveryComOrderViewModel());
            PageViewModels.Add(new FillOrderViewModel());

            // Set starting page
            CurrentUserControl = PageViewModels[0];
        }

        #region Fields

        private List<IUserContentViewModel> _pageViewModels;
        public List<IUserContentViewModel> PageViewModels
        {
            get
            {
                if (_pageViewModels == null)
                    _pageViewModels = new List<IUserContentViewModel>();

                return _pageViewModels;
            }
        }

        private IUserContentViewModel _currentUserControl;
        public IUserContentViewModel CurrentUserControl
        {
            get { return _currentUserControl; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _currentUserControl)
                {
                    _currentUserControl = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentUserControl");
                }
            }
        }

        #region Methods

        private void ChangeViewModel(IUserContentViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!PageViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
                PageViewModels.Add(viewModel);

            CurrentUserControl = PageViewModels
                .FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);


        }

        #endregion

        private ICommand _changePageCommand;
        #endregion
        public ICommand ChangePageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_changePageCommand == null)
                {
                    _changePageCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        p => ChangeViewModel((IUserContentViewModel)p),
                        p => p is IUserContentViewModel);
                }

                return _changePageCommand;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, when I am on the NewRegularOrderView I want to click on a button to navigate to FillOrderView.

The view is well changed in ChangeViewModel(IUserContentViewModel viewModel)
but it's not executed in the RelayCommand

## **NewRegularOrderView**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <cvm:CateringMenuViewModel x:Key="menu"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Border Grid.Row="2" Margin="10, 5" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="2">
            <Button DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource menu}}"
                    Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter ="{Binding PageViewModels[2]}"/>
</Border>
```

## **FillOrderView and ViewModel**

```
public class FillOrderViewModel : ViewModelBase, IUserContentViewModel
    {
        public FillOrderViewModel() {}

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "Fill Order";
            }
        }
    }

<UserControl.Resources>
        <cvm:FillOrderViewModel x:Key="fill"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource fill}}">
        <DataGrid Margin="405,100,395,110" >

        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
```

## **Update**

A light answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431473/navigate-between-usercontrols)

Comment: I think that I know what is your problem now, but one question before, you want to change to `NewDeliveryComOrderView` or `FillOrderView`?

Comment: @Kirenenko NewRegularOrderView to FillOrderView

Comment: I think the problem is the same that in the last question...You have to add this code to your `CateringMenuView UserControl.Resources`: `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cvm:FillOrderViewModel}">
            <cv:FillOrderView/>
 </DataTemplate>`. If this isn't the fail, at least this is "part" of the fail.

Comment: @Kirenenko No, I added it.

Comment: Try using the same parameters in your `NewRegularOrderView`  Command, than in your `CateringMenuView` Command: `Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource menu}}"`. If this does not work, check if your FillOrderViewModel constructor its being called.

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100640/discussion-between-kirenenko-and-cantinou).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kirenenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785282/302677) is correct that you have two separate instances of `CateringMenuViewModel`

When you type

```
<cvm:CateringMenuViewModel x:Key="menu"/>
```

you are telling WPF to create a new instance of `CateringMenuViewModel` and assign it the key/name/identifier of "menu", so you have one copy created in `CateringMenuView` and a second copy created in `NewRegularOrderView`. Naturally, changing the `CurrentUserControl` property of one does not affect the other.

There are two common solutions to this kind of situations.

1. Use some form of Event System to have `NewRegularOrderViewModel` broadcast a message of some kind, and have `CateringMenuViewModel` listen for those types of messages, and change the `CurrentUserControl` when it hears one.
2. Pass the `CateringMenuViewModel` (or method delegate) to the `NewRegularOrderViewModel` so it can call the `ChangePageCommand` directly. Korenenko's answer is attempting to show you one solution to do this.

Personally, I prefer #1 for something like this in most cases if possible, although #2 is also acceptable in most cases.

I find most of my WPF applications have some kind of messaging system used, so it makes sense to me to use it in cases like this where you want one ViewModel to alter another that it doesn't have any direct reference to. I have a few examples written about it [here](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/) or [here](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/) if you're interested.

Comment: I try to use your Simplifying PRISM’s EventAggregator but only Prism 6.0 is now available and 'CompositePresentationEvent<TEvent> GetEvent<TEvent>()' could not be found.

Comment: @Cantinou I'm not sure if Microsoft changed their namespaces at all, but it should be in `Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Events`. Did you make sure to include a `using` statement for that library?

Comment: Find it, `CompositePresentationEvent<TEvent>` has been replaced by `PubSubEvent<TEvent>`.

Comment: @Cantinou Good to know! :)

Comment: I have solved the issue with Event Aggregator. But it created another problem. Could you take a look at this question please? And thanks a lot for your precious advices.                                                                                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987514/model-viewmodel-and-datacontext?noredirect=1#comment57703423_34987514

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling 2 diferent instances of `CateringMenuViewModel`. You have to give your NewRegularOrderViewModel an instance of his Parent viewModel(CateringViewModel in your case) to use the same instance of the DataContext to call the same command.

In your **CateringMenuViewModel**:

```
PageViewModels.Add(new NewRegularOrderViewModel(this)); <- add this 
PageViewModels.Add(new NewDeliveryComOrderViewModel());
PageViewModels.Add(new FillOrderViewModel());
```

In your **NewRegularOrderViewModel**:

```
public CateringMenuViewModel Parent;
public NewRegularOrderView(): this(null)
{
}

public NewRegularOrderView(CateringMenuViewModel _Parent) {
    Parent = _Parent;
}

private ICommand _changePageCommand; 

public ICommand ChangePageCommand
{
    get {
        if (_changePageCommand == null)
        {
            _changePageCommand = new RelayCommand(
                p => ChangeViewModel((IUserContentViewModel)p),
                p => this.CanChangePageCommand);
        }

        return _changePageCommand;
    }
}

bool CanChangePageCommand
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

private void ChangeViewModel(IUserContentViewModel viewModel)
{
     Parent.CurrentUserControl = viewModel;   
}
```

In your **NewRegularOrderView**:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ChangePageCommand}" 
        CommandParameter ="{Binding Parent.PageViewModels[2]}"/>
```

`Datacontext` is supressed here because its pointing to your NewRegularOrderViewModel.

I've done this without any editor, so let me know if you have any doubt or something fails.

Comment: But there is no binding to ChangePageCommand (NewRegularOrderViewModel)? The button is on disable mode.

Comment: I have got the Object reference not set to an instance of an object error at the line `Parent.CurrentUserControl = viewModel;`

Comment: IUserContentViewModel viewModel is emtpy